# phpMyAdmin keeps resetting root password alone

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

Yesterday while I was trying to log in to phpMyAdmin, I couldn't and got this error

> "#1045 - access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password yes) "

So I reset my password, and today while trying to log in with the password I set yesterday I got the same error, any one know what is that?

Comment: After reset password yesterday, were u able to log in?

Comment: yeah, but today once I try to log into it, it shows the same error